# Sending out POST request returns with "text is empty"

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, iot, esp8266

I am trying to send a POST request using WiFiClientSecure on my ESP8266. It seems that the connection itself works, but when I send the request, I get back the following message:

> {"message":"text is empty (possibly
> HTTP/0.9)","traceId":"576eb1f7-3a18-7759-eaa1-8d0675f14fea"}

Here´s the portion of my code which sends the request. Any idea what I am doing wrong (net is my WiFiClientSecure instance)?

```
  if(!net.connect("xxx-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com", 8443)){
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    char err_buf[1024];
    Serial.println(net.getLastSSLError(err_buf,1024));
    Serial.printf("ssl_error: %s\n", err_buf);
    return;
  }else{
    Serial.println("Yeah!");
  }
  net.print("POST /topics/gaswarner?qos=1 HTTP/1.1\n" \
               "Host: xxx-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:8443\n" \
               "User-Agent: curl/7.74.0\n" \
               "Accept: */*\n" \
               "Content-Type: application/json\n" \
               "Content-Length: 19\n\n" \
               "{\"message\":\"hello\"}\n" \
               "Connection: close\n\n");
  Serial.println("Sent out..");

  while (net.connected()) {
    String line = net.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (line == "\r") {
      Serial.println("headers received");
      break;
    }
  }

  Serial.println("reply was:");
  Serial.println("==========");
  String line;
  while(net.available()){
    line = net.readStringUntil('\n');  //Read Line by Line
    Serial.println(line); //Print response
  }
  Serial.println("==========");
  Serial.println("closing connection");
```

Sending out that request using curl works as expected:

> curl.exe -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" --tlsv1.2 --cacert
> "pathtoCaCert" --cert
> "pathToCert" --key
> "pathToKey" --request POST
> --data "{ "message": "Hello, world" }" "https://xxx-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:8443/topics/gaswarner?qos=1"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try replacing the \n's in the request with \r\n or even better, use `ESP8266HTTPClient` rather than implementing HTTP yourself.

Comment: Move `"Connection: close\n\n");` to the front of http body `"{\"message\":\"hello\"}\n" `. The http body should be after all the http headers separated by extra `\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested @hcheung solution and it worked!
So for reference I´ll provide the code here. Keep in mind that using the ESP8266HTTPClient would have been a cleaner solution:

```
  net.print("POST /topics/gaswarner?qos=1 HTTP/1.1\n" \
               "Host: xxx-ats.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:8443\n" \
               "User-Agent: curl/7.74.0\n" \
               "Accept: */*\n" \
               "Content-Type: application/json\n" \
               "Content-Length: 19\n" \
               "Connection: close\n\n"\
               "{\"message\":\"hello\"}\n");
```